# Can I reference an array dynamically to perform a math function?

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic, reference

I have 18 static arrays with 18 values each.

I tried stuffing them into a gigantic 2-dimension array, but it crashes the compiler every time.

I already realized it's too much data, but I need every single one of these values for a series of complex equations.

I need this to be more efficient because I'm going to have to do this several times.

If I could just write code to dynamically pick an array, this would be easy.

A 2-component picker is used to select 2 values (18 choices). 
The 18 choices correspond to 18 values in 18 arrays.
The array I need to get dynamically is determined by the 2nd component(1) aka choice2.

```
choice1 = picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
choice2 = picker.selectedRowInComponent(1)
```

user picks the value being converted

```
numberToConvert = 345.0
```

Here is an example of what the Arrays look like:

```
let factorArray0 = [0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764]
let factorArray1 = [0.3544, 0.2053, 0.5854, 0.7452, 0.2379, 0.3042, 0.3595, 0.4101, 0.4438, 0.5098, 0.6448, 0.5165, 0.8691, 1.0000, 1.1354, 1.3688, 1.6125, 1.7446]
let factorArray2 = [0.6544, 0.1033, 0.7854, 0.2452, 0.2375, 0.3022, 0.3525, 0.4701, 0.5038, 0.5011, 0.6488, 0.9165, 0.8291, 1.0000, 1.0354, 1.3388, 1.3125, 1.7166]
```

etc.... 18 different arrays total
This is what I'm currently using to get the job done:

```
var conversionFactor:Double = 0.0000

if choice1 == 0 {
        conversionFactor = factorArray0[choice2]
    }else if choice1 == 1 {
        conversionFactor = factorArray1[choice2]
    }else if choice1 == 2 {
        conversionFactor = factorArray2[choice2]
    }else if choice1 == 3 {
        conversionFactor = factorArray3[choice2]
    }else if choice1 == 4 {
        conversionFactor = factorArray4[choice2]
    }else if choice1 == 5 {
        conversionFactor = factorArray5[choice2]
    }
//and so on.... if statement for every index 0-17 (18 total values)
```

The if statement is way too long. I've too much efficient programming to know that anything long is probably wrong. If I could REFERENCE array names in an array I could do this:

```
let arrayOfArrays = [[factorArray1],[factorArray2],[factorArray3],[factorArray4],....[factorArray17]]
//**please imagine the above array is filled with contents of those arrays so I don't paste a gigantic array or arrays**
conversionFactor = arrayOfArrays[choice1][choice2]
```

That works with stuffing entire small arrays, but with so many values, it can't even compile.

The final product is:

```
answer = conversionFactor * numberToConvert
```

Question: Does anyone have a more elegant solution? I figured something with enumerate might work but couldn't quite think of how. In the end I need to use CoreData but I'm looking for a temporary solution because all my searches for how to get and retrieve arrays of data haven't been successful. The course I'm taking will teach me CoreData, but I have a deadline so I need just a temporary solution or someone to tell me what tutorial or part of CoreData can help me.

Comment: Did you use a playground? If yes try it in a compiled source file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an 18 x 18 array is not huge.  It's not even big.  In fact it's Tiny!

You should indeed set up a two dimensional array.

```
var conversions = [[Double]]
```

Second, you should fill these up as such

```
conversions = [[1.1,1.2,1.3,....],[2.2,2.2,2.3],[....],...]
```

with all of your values.

Then your function should be

```
func conversionFactor (choice1:Int,choice2:Int) -> Double {
    return conversions[choice1][choice2]
}
```

This is on a global level.  You should probably wrap it in a class

```
class Conversion {
    var conversions:[[Int]] = [[1.1,1.2,1.3,....],[2.2,2.2,2.3],[....],...]
    class func conversionFactor (choice1:Int,choice2:Int) -> Double {
        return conversions[choice1][choice2]
    }
}

let conversion = Conversion.conversionFactor(1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use a 2 dimensional array, 18x18 is not big enough to cause a problem. I checked for myself and this compiles fine:

```
import Foundation

let factorTable = [[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764],
[0.0595, 0.1682, 0.2668, 0.1075, 0.2711, 0.3479, 0.4099, 0.4285, 0.6767, 0.6486, 0.5290, 0.9579, 1.0000, 1.3147, 1.2999, 1.6438, 1.6542, 2.0764]
]

struct BigArrays {
    init() {
        let choice1 = 9
        let choice2 = 13
        print(factorTable[choice1][choice2])
    }
}
```

Comment: My numbers have 10 significant digits after the decimal.. could that be the problem? Any chance you want to see if your compiler gets stuck on indexing when you make an array with that many decimals?